# Навигация по HTML обьекту jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

Есть подобная структура кода:

```
<div class="lang-line">
   <div class="sh-name">ab</div>
   <div class="lo-name">Abkhazian</div>
</div>
<div class="lang-line">
   <div class="sh-name">aa</div>
   <div class="lo-name">Afar</div>
</div>
```

Хочу настроить быстрый поиск языка, так что добавил все в обьект JQ:

```
$.each($('.langs .lang-line'), function() {
    l.push([$(this)]);
});
```

Но я не могу разобраться как использовать эти обьекты. Мне нужно сверять их название с введеным и если оно совпадает то все остальные обьекты должны быть скрыты, а этот остаться видимым:

Вот я пытался это реализовать:

```
for (var j=0; j<strArray.length; j++) {
    console.log(strArray[0].{0}.innerText);
    if (strArray[j][0][0][1].toLowerCase().match(str.toLowerCase())) {
        output.push(strArray[j].text());
        $(".lang-line").addClass("lang-line-srchprog");
        strArray[j].parent().style("display", "table");
    }
}
```

`output` - массив содержащий информацию которая будет выведена позже;
`strArray` - тот же массив `l` только принят функцией;
`str` - текст который был введен пользователем (пользователь вводит в input что он хочет найти).

Вот так выглядит сам обьект: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как получить доступ ко всем этим параметрам? В особенности мне нужен innerText/textContent что бы сравнить сразу короткое название и длинное одновременно(так как оно ведь считывает содержимое всех чилдренов, верно?)

Comment: что за `strArray`,  что за `output`, что за введенный текст и где он?

Comment: @teran я предположил что это было понятно, поправил вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте что-то около этого:

```js
function filterLang(contains) {
  contains = contains.toLowerCase(); // к нижнему регистру
  $('.langs .lang-line').each((i, el) => {
    let $langLine = $(el);
    let langName = $langLine.text().toLowerCase(); // текст блока с id и именем языка
    let isContains = langName.indexOf(contains) >= 0; // чекаем содержит ли в себе
    $langLine.css('display', (isContains ? '' : 'none')); // скрываем если не содержит иначе показываем
  });
}

$('#searcher').keyup(e => {
  filterLang($(e.target).val());
});
```

```css
.sh-name {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="searcher" type="text">

<div class="langs">
  <div class="lang-line">
    <div class="sh-name">ab</div>
    <div class="lo-name">Abkhazian</div>
  </div>
  <div class="lang-line">
    <div class="sh-name">aa</div>
    <div class="lo-name">Afar</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Тут происходит строгая проверка вместо "не строгой" как у меня. Я делаю так что даже при неполностью введеном слове будет результат. Да и вопрос в другом, я его немного обновил только что и добавил картинку. Не подскажете как получить доступ ко всем тем параметрам? Мне нужен этот `textContent` для проверки на совпадение.

Comment: @Telion не понял про вашу "строгость". У вас сравниваются строки с помощью регулярной `.match()`, которая в случае просто проверки на вхождения подстроки в строку в хорошем случае не используется, т.к она более прожерливая. И, как вы сказали "Я делаю так что даже при неполностью введеном слове будет результат" - это тут очень даже красиво отрабатывает.

Comment: А если верить сайту мозиллы то "indexOf() возвращает индекс первого вхождения указанного значения в строковый объект", а, например, на 2 буквы должны будут откликнуться сразу несколько языков. Впрочем это совершенно не важно для меня сейчас. Вопрос лишь в том как достать данные для проверки, так как я не понимаю эти обьекты в JQ, остальное не так сложно.

Comment: @Telion все верно, индекс первого вхождения и возвращает -1 если таковой подстроки не содержит. Если можете заметить, у меня проверка-то `.indexOf() >= 0`.

Comment: @Telion и честно говоря, я не понимаю что вы делаете в вашем коде и зачем постоянно все оборачиваете в массивы. Если вы хотите поменять поведение отображения элементов, просто работайте с ними после `let isContains = ...` в моем варианте, где `$langLine` - это jQuery элемент текущего `.lang-line` блока.

Comment: По сути там только 1 массив: массив обьектов языков, в котором и будут все названия языков для проверки, а так же обьект что бы легко ним манипулировать. Весь цикл `for` это просто функция, я ничего особо не делают, просто `l` -> `strArray` и в `str` то что ввел пользователь. Я сверяю языки в `strArray` и `str` и скрываю все языки которые не подходят под критерии. В плане я так себе представляю схему поиска по обьектам, вы видите это иначе? Я бы выслушал другие варианты.

Comment: То есть если что-то непонятно попробую максимально чисто выложить: на странице есть 100+ языков(короткое и полное название), так как их так много чисто для удобства пользователя я ввожу на сайт поиск по этим языкам что бы можно было быстрее найти нужный, но при этом не строгий, я думаю так будет лучше. При вводе данных скрываются все языки что не проходят проверку, а остальные это не 1, а множество прошедших проверку. Для проверки я просто сверяю: "ab Abkhazian" и "ab", прозодит? Да. Оставляем его видимым. "aa Afar" не содержит тех букв и скрывается.

Comment: @Telion так понял под "нестрогой" проверкой вы подразумеваете включение id языка в поиск? Исправил ответ.

Comment: @Telion посмотрите как сейчас у меня это работает и, если вас не устроит - выложите полностью степы и ожидания.

Comment: Окей, я баран =) Я только сейчас понял почему я был не прав и чем загвоздка с indexOf. Окей, я солидно вас тут задержал из-за этого. Спасибо за ответ и терпение!